# Ember (without ember-data) caching of data and defers

Tags: model, ember.js, jquery-deferred

I've been experimenting with using Emberjs without ember-data. I am trying to connect to an existing JSON *(but not REST)* API.

I am trying to load a grid of thumbnail images and present a high-res preview of whichever image is selected by clicking on it.

THe API has separate calls for getting a collection of files to getting the details of an individual file. Clearly, I would like to avoid making 100s of calls just to get hold of the preview hi-res image URL. Thus my App.File.find and App.File.findAll use different API calls.

`IMS.api.call` is a simple wrapper around `jQuery.ajax` that returns a promise.

**The problem:** the grid loads fine (`/#/files/`) but, if I click on an individual image, the preview uses the thumbnail not the preview image (`/#/files/11659315501`). However, if I refresh the browser then I get a high-res version.

Adding some logging I see that in the first version `App.File.find` is never called. On refresh it gets called once.

*Things I've tried:*

I added a computed property that makes separate call to grab the hi-res url:

```
bigUrl: function(){
    var id = this.get('content.id');
    preview = App.File.find(id);
    return preview.url;         
}.property('id')
```

but the defer returned by the jQuery call hadn't loaded by the time the view rendered so the bigUrl was undefined. So I tried wrapping that in a promise but Ember complained that a computed property can't return a promise.

I've looked everywhere to find how to encourage ember to call `App.File.find` but to no avail.

Any ideas?

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('files',function(){
    this.resource('file',{path:':file_id'});
  });
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function(){
        this.transitionTo('files');
    }
});

App.FilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.File.findAll();
  }
});

App.FileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(args) {
        return App.File.find(args.file_id);
    }
});

App.File = Ember.Object.extend({});
App.File.reopenClass({
    find: function(id){
        return IMS.api.call("Files.GetAssetDetails",{"assetId":id}).then(
            function(response) {
                file = response.outParams;
                return App.File.create({'id':file.id,'filename':file.filename,"url":file.panoramicUrl});
            }
        );
    },  

    findAll: function() {
        return IMS.api.call("Files.GetAssetsForParent",{"containerId":11659314773}).then(
            function(response) {
                var files = [];
                response.outParams.forEach(function (file) {
                    files.push(App.File.create({'id':file.id,'filename':file.filename,"url":file.thumbUrl}));
                });
                return files;
            }
        );
    },
});
```

[update]

The views look like this:

Application:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
      <h1>/pics/</h1>
      <hr>
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

Files:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="files">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="six columns">
        {{outlet}}
      </div>

      <div class="six columns" id='chooser'>
        {{#each file in model}}
        <div style='float:left'>
          <div>
            {{#linkTo file file}}
              <img {{bindAttr src="file.url"}} style='width:100px;height:100px;'>
            {{/linkTo}}
          </div>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

File

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="file">
{{log id}}{{log url}}
  <div>
  <img {{bindAttr src="url"}} style='width:400px;height:400px;'>
  </div>
  <div>
    {{id}}
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: could you post the file index template? i suspect you might be passing a file object as context with a linkTo there.

Comment: You mean, like: `{{#linkTo file file}}` ?

Comment: yes, i meant that. but on second thought it's probably that a file with the right id has already been loaded for the index and that you just need to refresh/update it somehow.

Comment: I've tried that - adding a second ajax call that goes through all the files and sets the url to the bigger value. It didn't work as despite the data being updated the view never refreshed.

Comment: have tried doing it in the `setupController` hook of your `FileRoute`?

Comment: That seems to do it. I didn't realise that `setupController` gets called each time a route is changed. I think it would be better named `updateController`

Answer (score 2):

To force your model to be reloaded each time the route changes you need to make the call from the `setupController`.

A `setupController` is called each time the route changes. I've chosen to call the model as a function rather than repeat the `App.File.find` call.

```
App.FileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller,model){
        console.log("setupController",controller,model);
        controller.set('model',this.model({file_id:model.id}));
    },
    model: function(params) {
        return App.File.find(params.file_id);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work if you are returning a promise. To get it to work you have to return an object and promise to fill it in later.

```
find: function(id){
    file = App.File.create({});
    IMS.api.call("Files.GetAssetDetails",{"assetId":id,"fields":{"metadata":true}}).then(function(response) {
        file.setProperties({'id':response.outParams.id,'filename':response.outParams.filename,"url":response.outParams.panoramicUrl,"metadata":response.outParams.metadata});
        }
    );
    return file;
},
```

This does leave one occasional error:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'response.outParams.id')

This is caused by `setupController` not getting a valid id from the model and then handing undefined to find the first time it calls it.

There must be a better way of getting the id from the route... anyone?

**[UPDATE]**

Here's how I stopped the error:

```
setupController: function(controller,model){
    if(model.isLoaded == false){
        controller.set('model',model);
    } else {
        controller.set('model',this.model({file_id:model.id}));
    }
},
```

and I added an '.isLoaded' flag to my find function:

```
find: function(id){
    file = App.File.create({isLoaded: false});
    IMS.api.call("Files.GetAssetDetails",{"assetId":id,"fields":{"metadata":true}}).then(function(response) {
        file.setProperties({'id':response.outParams.id,'filename':response.outParams.filename,"url":response.outParams.panoramicUrl,"metadata":response.outParams.metadata});
        file.set('isLoaded', true);
    });
    return file;
},
```

Comment: Did you considered using the `afterModel` hook? It works well with promises.